# How I can know the equivalent DBPedia and Wikidata properties

Tags: rdf, dbpedia, wikidata

Could someone tell me how i can find the synonym property of DBPedia in Wikidata? for example, the property "name" in DBpedia is "label" in Wikidata. 
How I can find all the synonyms properties?

Answer (score 10):

### Further EDIT...

Querying DBpedia delivers [a much larger set (228, as of 2023-10-25) of equivalency mappings](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX+++++++owl%3A++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX++++++rdfs%3A++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+%3FDBpediaProp+%3FitemLabel+%3FWikidataProp%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A++%7B%0D%0A++++%3FDBpediaProp++owl%3AequivalentProperty++%3FWikidataProp+.%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++FILTER+%28+CONTAINS+%28+str%28%3FWikidataProp%29+%2C+%27wikidata%27+%29+%29+.%0D%0A++++%3FDBpediaProp++rdfs%3Alabel++++++++++++++%3FitemLabel+.%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++FILTER+%28lang%28%3FitemLabel%29+%3D+%27en%27%29%0D%0A++%7D%0D%0AORDER+BY++%3FDBpediaProp&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on), obtained with a rather different yet very similar query.

```
PREFIX       owl:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX      rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?DBpediaProp ?itemLabel ?WikidataProp
WHERE
  {
    ?DBpediaProp  owl:equivalentProperty  ?WikidataProp .
                  FILTER ( CONTAINS ( str(?WikidataProp) , 'wikidata' ) ) .
    ?DBpediaProp  rdfs:label              ?itemLabel .
                  FILTER (lang(?itemLabel) = 'en')
  }
ORDER BY  ?DBpediaProp
```

### EDIT springing from @Tom Morris' answer##

This query can be run on the Wikidata endpoint, https://query.wikidata.org/. For completeness and increased portability, I include the `PREFIX` declarations (even though that endpoint auto-applies them).  I also `FILTER` to get only the `dbpedia` equivalencies; you can strike that line to include equivalencies from `schema.org` and possibly other ontologies.

*EDIT again — Wikidata syntax has changed slightly; I've updated the query below to match.*

```
PREFIX       wdt:  <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX  wikibase:  <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX        bd:  <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#>

SELECT ?WikidataProp ?WikidataPropLabel ?DBpediaProp
WHERE
  {
    ?WikidataProp  wdt:P1628  ?DBpediaProp .
    FILTER ( CONTAINS ( str(?DBpediaProp) , 'dbpedia' ) ) .
    SERVICE wikibase:label
      { bd:serviceParam  wikibase:language  "en" } .
  }
```

and you get <strike>(as of this writing) [a whopping *two* such equivalencies](https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20%20wikibase%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwikiba.se%2Fontology%23%3E%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.bigdata.com%2Frdf%23%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%3FWikidataProp%20%3FWikidataPropLabel%20%3FDBpediaProp%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FWikidataProp%20%20wdt%3AP1628%20%20%3FDBpediaProp%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20(%20CONTAINS%20(%20str(%3FDBpediaProp)%20%2C%20%27dbpedia%27%20)%20)%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%20%22en%22%20%7D%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)</strike> [a whopping *35* such equivalencies, as of 2023-10-25](https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20%20wikibase%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwikiba.se%2Fontology%23%3E%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.bigdata.com%2Frdf%23%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%3FWikidataProp%20%3FWikidataPropLabel%20%3FDBpediaProp%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FWikidataProp%20%20wdt%3AP1628%20%20%3FDBpediaProp%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20(%20CONTAINS%20(%20str(%3FDBpediaProp)%20%2C%20%27dbpedia%27%20)%20)%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%20%22en%22%20%7D%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D).

### My Original Answer

I do not believe a full cross-mapping is available anywhere, and for various reasons (not least being that these ontologies were not designed to be exactly synonymous), may never be.

That said, you might look at [the DBpedia Mapping Wiki](http://mappings.dbpedia.org/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=wikidata&fulltext=Search).

You can find much discussion....

- [Wikidata/Notes/DBpedia and Wikidata](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wikidata/Notes/DBpedia_and_Wikidata)
- [Google Summer of Code 2013 Ideas: Wikidata Mappings](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/get-involved/google-summer-code/gsoc-2013/ideas/wikidata-mappings)
- [Wikidata:Requests for comment/Can we reuse anything from DBpedia?](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Requests_for_comment/Can_we_reuse_anything_from_DBpedia%3F)
- [DBpedia-based RDF dumps for Wikidata](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/news/dbpedia-based-rdf-dumps-wikidata)
- [Wikidata through the Eyes of DBpedia](http://www.semantic-web-journal.net/content/wikidata-through-eyes-dbpedia)

Comment: How can we get the Wikidata label in first query for WikidataProp?

Comment: @MarceloMachado — Your query fails, with `Unknown error: Service URI http://query.wikidata.org/bigdata/namespace/wdq/wikiba.se/ontology#label is not allowed`. At minimum, you should have wrapped it in backticks for viability in a comment. I'll paste that here in a moment (too many characters for a single comment)...

Comment: @MarceloMachado — As suggested, `PREFIX wdt: <http://wikidata.org/prop/direct> PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#> PREFIX bd: <http://bigdata.com/rdf#> SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?DBpediaProp WHERE { ?item wdt:P1628 ?DBpediaProp . FILTER ( CONTAINS ( str(?DBpediaProp) , 'dbpedia' ) ) . SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" } . }` ... but this also fails, with `Unknown error: Expected a variable in the object position to which to bind the language.` I see no quick fix to this error.

Comment: @TallTed the copy and paste was sabotaging me. Let's try again:

`PREFIX       wdt:  <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX  wikibase:  <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX        bd:  <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#>


SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?DBpediaProp WHERE { 
  ?item wdt:P1628 ?DBpediaProp . 
  FILTER ( CONTAINS ( str(?DBpediaProp) , 'dbpedia' ) ) . 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" } . 
}`

You need to replace `?WikidataProp` and `?WikidataPropLabel` respectively to `?item` and `?itemLabel`.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't appear to be well populated, but I'd expect DBpedia properties to show up in Wikidata's `P1628` "Equivalent Property"

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?equivProp
WHERE
{
    ?item wdt:P1628 ?equivProp .
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

example result:

```
item      itemLabel      equivProp
wd:P200   lake inflows   <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/inflow>
```